# Is it possible to select string with utf8decode?

Tags: sql-server

I have a bunch of string in my database encoded as utf8.
What i'm trying to do is getting encoded string back to utf8decode string without any of my application modification but like this ->

```
select utf8decode(varchar column)...
```

I'm in awe with this now, any advice would be appreciate...

Comment: Are you sure you're using Microsoft SQL Server?  If not, change your tag from `sql-server` to `mysql` for example.

Comment: My mssql table has a set of data from informix...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best solution is to use CLR function. Example you can find here:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/utfConvert.aspx

Another solution is to use varbinary column to store text data as binary data and then convert it to text when selecting.